# newsletter: Image size for iPhone client

Tags: iphone, newsletter

when I send newsletter with images exceeds 100kB altogether, iPhone mail client just show plain text and images like mime-attachment. Only if I touch Download full message button, newsletter shows as HTML.

But I dont see this behaviour in another newsletters.

What determined when image shows or plain text only?

Thank you